# How to use functions with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

How can I use function with pandas dataframe. For example:

```
a       | b
london  | uk
newyork | usa
berlin  | germany

df1 = df[['a', 'b']]

def doSomething(df1):
    return df1
```

`doSomething()` will return both columns `a` and `b`, But how do I return say only `a`?

```
def doSomething(df1):
    return df1.a 

df1.applymap(doSomething)

AttributeError: ("'str' object has no attribute 'a'", u'occurred at index a')
```

Comment: `df1['a']` does not work ?

Comment: `applymap` calls the function on every *element* of the dataframe

Comment: @MMF no it does not. I'm getting `TypeError: ('string indices must be integers, not str', u'occurred at index a')`

Comment: @DevEx Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['london','newyork','berlin'],
                   'b':['uk','usa','germany'],
                   'c':[7,8,9]})

print (df)
df1 = df[['a', 'b']]

def doSomething(x):
    return x.a

#function works with DataFrame 
print (doSomething(df1))
0     london
1    newyork
2     berlin
Name: a, dtype: object

#function works with Series, columns are transformed to index of Series
#return for each row value of Series with index a which is transformed to column in output df
print (df1.apply(doSomething, axis=1))
0     london
1    newyork
2     berlin
dtype: object
```

If need [`applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) it works with each element of `df`:

```
def doSomething(x):
    return x + '___'

#function works with element
print (df1.applymap(doSomething))
            a           b
0   london___       uk___
1  newyork___      usa___
2   berlin___  germany___
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df1 = df[['a', 'b']]

def doSomething(df):
df2 = df['a']
return df2

df3 = df1.apply(doSomething, axis=1)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(df3).rename(columns={0: 'a'})
```