# Use function to modify pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

This is a follow up of the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41015805/how-to-use-functions-with-pandas-dataframe/41015945#41015927):
How to modify a dataframe using function? Lets say I want to make call `.upper()` on values in `a`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['london','newyork','berlin'],
                   'b':['uk','usa','germany'],
                   'c':[7,8,9]})

df1 = df[['a', 'b']]

def doSomething(x):
    return x.a

print (df1.apply(doSomething, axis=1))
0     london
1    newyork
2     berlin
dtype: object

call `.upper()` on values in `a`:
return 
0     LONDON
1     NEWYORK
2     BERLIN
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call function for column `a`:

```
def doSomething(x):
    return x.upper()

print (df1.a.apply(doSomething))
0     LONDON
1    NEWYORK
2     BERLIN
Name: a, dtype: object
```

---

```
print (df1.a.apply(lambda x: x.upper()))
0     LONDON
1    NEWYORK
2     BERLIN
Name: a, dtype: object
```

Also it works with:

```
def doSomething(x):
    return x.a.upper()

print (df1.apply(doSomething, axis=1))
0     LONDON
1    NEWYORK
2     BERLIN
dtype: object
```

but better is use [`str.upper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.upper.html) which works perfectly with `NaN` values:

```
print (df1.a.str.upper())
0     LONDON
1    NEWYORK
2     BERLIN
Name: a, dtype: object
```

If need add new column:

```
df['c'] = df1.a.str.upper()
print (df)
         a        b        c
0   london       uk   LONDON
1  newyork      usa  NEWYORK
2   berlin  germany   BERLIN
```

Comment: How to add column `c` to this newly modified dataframe ?

Comment: thank you. Is it possible to add `c` in the `apply` solution?

Comment: Yes, same way like `df1['c'] = df1.a.apply(doSomething)` or `df1['c'] = df1.apply(doSomething, axis=1)`...